# Calling a model function in view

Tags: codeigniter

i am trying to access a function in model, in my view in codeigniter and its not working.
can somebody please tell me where is the problem.

MODEL:

```
function gettemplates()
    {
        $sql = "select * from srs_templates";
        $query =  $this->db->query($sql);
        $result = $query->result_array();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);exit;
        return $result;
    }
```

VIEW:

```
<select id="special" >
    <?php echo $this->dashboard_ext_model->gettemplates(); ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Why accessing the model in view? Check if the model is already loaded or not.

Comment: Tell use error what you got????

Comment: as you can see @Manwal i am trying to print the fetched values on the fourth line of the model function but the output is completely blank page and yes i have loaded the model.

Comment: The `exit`call prevents the function from returning $result, get rid of that. And yes, it's bad form to try and load models in views. Have the model pass its result to a controller, and have that controller pass it on to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);exit;
```

To this:

```
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
```

Basically remove the exit.  Exit aborts the script.

You should never have a good reason to call the model from the view.  Model data should be passed to the controller, to then pass to the view.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is MVC (Model View Controller) you shouldn't call a model from a view.
You should be calling the Model inside the controller then passing to the view as an argument.

Model:

```
function gettemplates()
{
    $sql = "select * from srs_templates";
    $query =  $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);exit;
    return $result;
}
```

Controller:

```
function gettemplates(){

     //$this->dashboard_ext_model = $this->load->model('dashboard_ext_model'); 
     //uncomment this if you didn't load the model

     $data['templates'] = $this->dashboard_ext_model->gettemplates();

     $this->view->load('page_name', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<select id="special" >
    <?php echo $templates ?>
</select>
```

MVC may look stupid at first but it really helps in large size projects.

MVC DESIGN: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Beh3a.png